# How to call aspx page including server side code in jquery load with out using jquery ajax method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a asp calendar control, it is included in update panel. When click on the date, SelectionChanged() event is not fired. Here is the code.

ASPX -

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar" runat="server" BorderColor="green" NextPrevStyle-BackColor="green"
BorderStyle="Solid" Height="414px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" TitleStyle-BackColor="green"
DayStyle-Font-Underline="false" ShowGridLines="True" Width="567px" onvisiblemonthchanged="Calendar_VisibleMonthChanged"
SelectedDate="02/23/2013 15:33:22" VisibleDate="2013-02-23" onselectionchanged="Calendar_SelectionChanged">
    <DayStyle Font-Underline="True" />
    <NextPrevStyle BackColor="green" />
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="green" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black"
    />
    <SelectorStyle Font-Bold="True" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="green" Font-Underline="False" />
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="green" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Calendar>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Calendar" EventName="SelectionChanged"
        />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server side code -

```
protected void Calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = CalEdairy.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        }
```

Comment: Subject is hardly a full question.. please provide specific details about what you are trying to accomplish. Also , please post real code without changing `<>` and wrap in code block

Comment: Did you make sure you actually chose a different selection. It's a selection changed event, so if the selection isn't changing, no event is going to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code and it's working fine for me.(except I removed onvisiblemonthchanged="Calendar_VisibleMonthChanged")

[image]